# JxBrowser distribution package

Tags: jxbrowser

According to this [page](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000022587-run-jxbrowser-demo-locally) the jxbrowser demo is in the distribution package. But have I been unable to find this package.  I currently have a personal license. Does anyone know where to download it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest JxBrowser 6.2 package from http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-6.2-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip